# How to implement mutex in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GCD : How to write and read to variable from two threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070947/gcd-how-to-write-and-read-to-variable-from-two-threads)

I am developing a iOS app in which i am using sqlite database.I have to perform multithreading  but on sqlite database I am able to do only one thing at a time.So I need to implement concept of semaphore .So plz help me

Comment: can you elaborate your question?
What exactly you want to do?

Comment: You kind of forgot to ask a question. Why not use [NSLock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: I want to ask how to synchronize database operation ?

Comment: The above-linked question has some ways of dealing with this exact same situation, with my personally preferred one of using a serial GCD queue for anything touching a shared resource like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@synchronized` directive as a mutex. If you have all your methods for manipulating the sqlite database in a single data manager created using a singleton and shared throughout the project you can use that object as the lock token, e.g.:

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)globalDataManager {
    @synchronized(globalDataManager) {
        // Everything between the braces is protected by the @synchronized directive.
    }
}
```

And from within the data manager you can use `@synchronized(self)` for the same protection.

You will only need a mutex for this so don't worry about extra code for implementing semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to implement concept of semaphore

semaphore implementations are found in `#include <sys/semaphore.h>`.